# autopopulate User signature field to a lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have one lightning Component which has one RichText Area field.
My requirement is that when the lightning component loaded, the RichTextArea should be prepopulated with the User's signature.
Signature field is 'Text Area' type.
I am able to bring the signature field into Richtext field but it's not getting populated in the same way as it it's in the User's record.

[image]

[image]

```
<aura:component controller='MessageCreationFromCaseController' implements='force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction' access='global'>
    <aura:attribute name="myVal" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.myVal}"/>
    <br/><lightning:button variant="brand" label="Create Message" title="Create Message" onclick="{!c.createMessage}" />
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.getUserSignature');
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){ 
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS') { 
                var responseVal = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('responseVal: '+responseVal);
                component.set('v.myVal', responseVal);
                
            } 
            else{
                console.log('ERROR...');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },
    createMessage : function(component, event, helper) {
        var richtext = component.get("v.myVal");
        var richTextStr = richtext.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');
        console.log('richtext: '+richTextStr);
    }
})
```

```
public class MessageCreationFromCaseController {
    
     @AuraEnabled
    public static String getUserSignature(){
        
        User u = [select id, Signature__c from User where id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        system.debug('sign: '+u.Signature__c);
        return u.Signature__c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the text in the underlying field? Does it contain any HTML markup like `<br/>`?

Comment: There is no html tags

Comment: You might try replacing carriage returns with HTML breaks before setting in the input...

Comment: Can you please guide how I can do carriage return.

Comment: Not got the chance to see if it would work just yet, but it may be as simple as using `String.replaceAll('\\r', '<br/>')` on the value you set in the rich text editor (and doing the opposite, as required, when retrieving).

Comment: Thanks a lot your solution worked for me, I did one simple change to it, instead of <br/> I used <pre/>, as <br/> was adding one extra space in the new line.
String.replaceAll('\\r', '<pre/>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the carriage returns in the signature text into HTML line breaks or similar by simply doing something like:

```
String signature = ...;
String theRichTextValue = signature.replaceAll('\\r', '<br/>');
```

Other block-like HTML elements could be used instead if you wish.